# How to adjust speed of turtlebot in Gmapping?

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was looking through some of the launch and node files and wasn't sure where to begin with adjusting turtlebots speed when executing a goal in gmapping or amcl? I want the robot to move a bit slower to clean up some of the jerkyness. Also like to include that I am using Diamondback on 10.10 with updated and basically stock turtlebot files(with the exception of adjusting the teleop packages to slow speed).  I am assuming the gmapping works differently than the teleop. Am I wrong?  Any advice appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11679/how-to-adjust-speed-of-turtlebot-in-gmapping?/) by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 458 on 2011-11-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Atom,

I haven't tried this with my TurtleBot, but I think you can lower the max_vel_x parameter in the file base_local_planner_params.yaml which is found in the config directory of the turtlebot_navigation package.  The default value is 0.50 m/s.  You might also try tweaking some other parameters in that file such as:

```
  min_vel_x: 0.10
  max_rotational_vel: 1.5
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 1.0
  acc_lim_th: 0.75
  acc_lim_x: 0.50
  acc_lim_y: 0.50
```

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-11-05**:
Great!  If you are happy with the answer, please click on the little checkmark above (only you can do that) and then the answer will appear as "answered" in the index.

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-11-05**:
I also reduced all the parameters you listed in half. ( trying to reduce the original speed by 1/2) Works better for me now, Although I will try using turtlebot calibrate to clean things up, or just keep playing with the numbers till I find the sweet spot.. Thanks Patrick

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-11-05**:
I changed values in the params.yaml as you suggested. Seems to do the trick. Although I did notice that my mapping with turtlebot in rviz was a bit faster in rotation than in reality. Which gave me a inaccurate map. So I ended up matching the values from my teleop.launch and  that helped...